# Overwrite Data in Excel file with OleDb C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

is it possible to overwrite data in cells with OleDb in C# with a specific row range?

I only found adding data to first empty cells in specific column like

```
string sql = "Insert into [Tabelle1$] (testA, testB) values(6,7)";
```

If its not possible what assembly is fast for this task ....Microsoft.Office.Interop is horrible slow.

Thanks for any tip

Comment: yes it is possible. Please check the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409823/excel-does-not-have-updated-values-using-oledb-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel does not have updated values using oledb c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409823/excel-does-not-have-updated-values-using-oledb-c-sharp)